# Sprout Email compiled_templates

Tags: plugin-sproutforms, plugin-sproutemail

I am having an issue whereby a form field is causing errors with Sprout Forms & Sprout Email to function.

I have found the root of the problem in that the field, `fullName` was causing errors, so changing it to `contactFullName` seemed like a good idea, as not to confuse matters with Craft's own field `fullName`.

When checking the logs after making these changes, sproutemail.log was still indicating an error related to the `fullName` field. Strange! I had changed this! It seems that there is a `craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/03/****.php` where *** is a long string filename used. Going to Settings -> Refreshing the compiled templates did not fix this either, so what can I do to refresh this compiled template to reflect my changes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete that folder entirely and it will get re-created on the next request that needs a template.

If it's not updating, chances are you've got some PHP byte-level caching extension installed like [APC](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) or [OPcache](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) that's not busting cache properly.